# Median Value via an Expression in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, and I'm trying to build a report that displays the Max, Min, Mean, and Median of my dataset.  I've done the Max, Min, and Mean via expressions, but I can't seem to figure out the Median.  Everything I have found online so far suggests writing VB code.  Is there a way to just write and expression similar to the others I've already done?

Example:

```
="Avg = " & (Format(Avg(Fields!CYCLE_DAYS.Value, "CycleTimesAll2014"),"#,##0.#"))
```

This doesn't work, but wish I could find something similar.

```
=Median(Fields!CYCLE_DAYS.Value, "CycleTimesAll2014")
```

Comment: What language is this in Visual Studio?  The code you included looks a lot like an excel command.

Comment: Visual studio is a front end that basically allows a user to design a report using tools.  I typed that excel looking command into a text box.  The reports are saved as a .rdl file and can be viewed in XML.